# How to make Loop stop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would appreciate some help with my code below. The code will go thru all the rows and if it finds a certain text string it  will execute some code. Then it will continue to the next cell that contains that text string and so on. What I cant figure out is that the loop keeps going endlessly. I'm not sure what I'm missing with the loop I created.

```
Sub FINDnSELECT()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Code As range

range("A1").Select

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS.UsedRange
        Set Code = .cells.Find(What:="TEST")
        If Not Code Is Nothing Then
            Do Until Code Is Nothing

              Code.Select
              'my code

              Set Code = .FindNext(Code)
            Loop
        End If
    End With
    Set Code = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Range.FindNext` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel):

> When the search reaches the end of the specified search range, **it wraps around to the beginning of the range**. To stop a search when this wraparound occurs, save the address of the first found cell, and then test each successive found-cell address against this saved address.

So instead of this:

> ```
> If Not Code Is Nothing Then
>     Do Until Code Is Nothing
> ```

You'll want something like this:

```
Dim firstFoundAddress As String

If Not Code Is Nothing Then
    firstFoundAddress = Code.Address
    Do
        '...
        Set Code = .FindNext(Code)
    While firstFoundAddress <> Code.Address
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm not sure what I'm missing with the loop I created.

You have the following:

> ```
> Dim Code As range
>
> ...
>
>             Do Until Code Is Nothing
>
> ...
>
>             Loop
> ```

However:

```
**Nothing**

This keyword/value can only be used with variables declared as Object or Variant
```

`Code` is not declared as type `Object` or `Variant`.

Source [VBA Data Types - Nothing](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/object-nothing.htm)

---

#### Further Reading

- [VBA Loops - For, Do-While and Do-Until Loops](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html#DoUntilLoop)

Comment: `Code` is declared `As Range`, and `Range` is an object type. It can absolutely be assigned to `Nothing`.